# Assigning String to a final String

Tags: java, string, object, static, final

I have a few classes like this:

```
public class A {
    private String foo;

    public A(String f) {
        foo = f; // I want foo to be final based on the subclass instance
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    private static final String FOO = "foo1";

    public B() {
        super(FOO);
    }
}

public class C extends A {
    private static final String = "foo2";

    public C() {
        super(FOO);
    }
}
```

What I want is when I create an object on type `B`, I don't want the `String` in `A` to be changeable. `foo = f` just assigns a reference but I want `foo` to be the same final object `FOO`. How can I do this?

Comment: You're misunderstanding references and mutability.  `String` is immutable.

Comment: I want to guarantee that foo is also either "foo1" or "foo2" and that no one can change it.

Comment: Then just make it `final`.  Also, consider using an enum.

Comment: If you want field `foo` to be final, declare it so: `private final String foo;`

Answer (score 2):

It appears you don't want a field at all, instead you can have a method.

```
interface A {
    String foo(); // the implementation depends on the sub-class.
}

class B implements A {
    public String foo() { return "foo1"; }
}

class C implements A {
    public String foo() { return "foo2"; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not the best in design but what you want to do is to initialize a final String.

```
public class A {
    private final String foo;

    public A(String f) {
        foo = f; 
    }
}
```

Final variables can be initialized only once, so you can initialize it in the constructor. But in your case that doesn't make sense because your subclasses are not able to access `foo` because it is private. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for all available Java visibility modifiers.